# only the first row were calculated automatically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

i have this table that has a column for the edit button. a modal will pop up and the data from the row selected will show when the button is clicked.

so on my edit modal, i have 3 textboxes: Quantity, Consumed, and Available.

```js
$('#edit-quant').keyup(function() {
  var quant;
  var consumed;
  quant = parseFloat($('#edit-quant').val());
  consumed = parseFloat($('#edit-consumed').val());
  avail = quant - consumed || 0;
  $("#edit-avail").val(avail);
});

$('#edit-consumed').keyup(function() {
  var quant;
  var consumed;
  quant = parseFloat($('#edit-quant').val());
  consumed = parseFloat($('#edit-consumed').val());
  avail = quant - consumed || 0;
  $("#edit-avail").val(avail);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group mb-3">

  <span class="input-group-text" style="color: #008080"><label>Quantity</label></span>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="edit-quant" name="edit-quant" placeholder="Quantity" value="2"></i>

  <span class="input-group-text" style="color: #008080"><label>Consumed</label></span>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="edit-consumed" name="edit-consumed" placeholder="Consumed" value="3">

  <span class="input-group-text" style="color: #008080"><label>Available</label></span>
  <input class="form-control" id="edit-avail" type="text" name="edit-avail" placeholder="Available" value="4" readonly>

</div>
```

and when i try to change the values of the Quantity and Consumed and calculates its Available. only the first row of the table were working. the proceeding rows remains the same. how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have these repeated.  You should not have an `id` attribute that is the same on any two or more elements on the same page.  When you select an element by its `id`, the first element found with that value is going to be returned.

What you can do is make these into classes, then to get the fields, you can find the `.closest(".input-group")` which is wrapping all of your fields.  From there, you can pull any of the fields by their given class.  Alternatively, just use the `name` attribute on the fields and get rid of the id all together.

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
     <span class="input-group-text" style="color: #008080"><label>Quantity</label></span>
     <input class="form-control" type="text" name="edit-quant" placeholder="Quantity" value="{{$med->med_quantity}}" ></i>   

     <span class="input-group-text" style="color: #008080"><label>Consumed</label></span>
     <input class="form-control"  type="text" name="edit-consumed" placeholder="Consumed" value="{{$med->med_consumed}}">

     <span class="input-group-text" style="color: #008080"><label>Available</label></span>
     <input class="form-control" type="text" name="edit-avail"  placeholder="Available" value="{{$med->med_available}}" readonly>
</div>
```

I've removed the `id` attributes from the three fields.  Now, when our event triggers, we'll find the group (parent DIV), and get each field with `.find()`.

```
$('input[name = "edit-quant"], input[name = "edit-consumed"]').keyup(function()
{
    var $group   = $(this).closest('.input-group');
    var quant    = parseFloat($group.find('input[name = "edit-quant"]').val());
    var consumed = parseFloat($group.find('input[name = "edit-consumed"]').val());

    $group.find('input[name = "edit-avail"]').val(quant - consumed || 0);
});
```

Untested, but should work for you, or at least get you on the right track.